# git update-index --assume-unchanged just stopped working

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

We use this command to ignore our appsettings.json files in our ASP.Net Core MVC application in Visual Studio 2017.

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged Doed.Aarts.Net.Web/appsettings.json
```

or

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Doed.Aarts.Net.Web/appsettings*.json
```

This was working perfectly for a long time.
Today I made a change to appsettings.json and noticed the change showed up in the changes.

I originally thought I just messed something up some how so I recloned the project to start from scratch.
Opened git bash and applied the assume unchanged command.

But I can't get it to work again.

Any advice on figuring out what could be going on here would be appreciated.

I've checked the pathways to make sure I am opening from the right place and pointing to the right path.

But still having problems.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually working for me everybody.
It was never really broken.  It's just been so long since I paid attention to it I forgot what everything looks like at each step of the way.

If anyone is looking at how to do this.

These are the correct commands:
To make it so that a file's changes will not be tracked as changed, and not sit there waiting to be staged:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged Doed.Aarts.Net.Web/appsettings.json
```

You could also use wild cards in names like appsettings*.json.

To turn if off use:

```
$ git update-index --no-assume-unchanged Doed.Aarts.Net.Web/appsettings*.json
```

So if I make a change to this file this is what it looks like in Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

Notice the star next to the file name in Team Explorer.

Now when I save the file it disappears from the changes.
But my local file retains the edit.

We use this in our project because the version in the source repo has tokens in appsettings that are replaced for various builds in different environments.  Each environment needs different values so we leave the tokens to be replaced.

But locally we replace the tokens with hard coded values needed to run and develop.

Hope this all makes sense and helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13630849/1256452).  I'm not going to close this as a duplicate (yet?) though.

> Today I made a change to appsettings.json and noticed the change showed up in the changes.

This requires more detail on your part, because "the changes" is ambiguous.  Do you mean it shows up in `git status`?  Do you mean that if you run `git diff` on two commits, the file shows as changed between those two commits?  Or do you mean something else entirely?

#### Important background to know

The *index*, which is also called the *staging area* and the *cache*, is a key Git data structure.  It contains every file that will go into each commit you make, and it starts out containing every file from the commit you have extracted into your work-tree (the directory where you do your work) from some starting commit.  That is, once you have a Git repository—a collection of commits—you start out by using `git checkout` to extract one *particular* commit into your index, and into a work-tree.

Generally this all happens on an initial `git clone`, whose last step is `git checkout master`.  This puts you onto your own (newly-created) branch named `master` at the same *tip commit* as your existing `origin/master`, all of which were obtained by the `git clone` command.  That is, `git clone`:

1. Creates a new, empty repository (a collection of zero commits), with a blank *index* and an empty work-tree.
2. *Fills* the repository from another Git (now you have many commits).  The index is still empty / blank, as is the work-tree.
3. Uses their branch names—their `master`, for instance—to create your *remote-tracking names*, such as `origin/master`.  Each such name identifies one commit.  Over time, you and your Git, plus the other Git from which you are cloning, will arrange for these names to identify some other—usually, newer—commit, though at any time each name will still identify exactly one commit.
4. Creates your own `master` based on the `origin/master` your Git just made based on *their* Git's `master`.  (All of this complexity is required to understand why your `master` and their `master` do not always identify the same particular commit.  They *start out* the same, and you'll often make them become the same again, once they become different.  They are separate, though!  Your `origin/master` is your Git's memory of their Git's `master`, so your `origin/master` follows their `master` around.  Your own `master` is *yours*, to do with as you will.)
5. Probably most important, your Git—as the last step of `git clone`—*extracts* the contents of this particular commit, *into* your index and *into* your work-tree.  That's where the files you will work on came from!

#### New commits are made from whatever is in the index

At various times, you will modify some file or files in the work-tree, then do:

```
git add file1 file2 ... fileN    # or git add --all, or git add ., etc
git commit                       # with options if desired
```

The new commit uses whatever files are stored in the *index* (not the work-tree!) to make the new commit.  The fact that Git uses the index, not the work-tree, is *why* you had to `git add` the changed files: the index started out holding *all* the files, and it still holds *all* the files, but the ones in the index did not change when you modified the ones in the work-tree.

What `git add path` does is to *copy* the work-tree file into the index, overwriting the copy that is currently in the index.  Hence, by adding the file, you have *changed* the version in the index (to match the version in the work-tree).  This means the *next* commit you make will have the new version of the file, instead of having the old version of the same file.

This is crucial since `git commit` uses the *index*, not the work-tree, to make the commit!  If you never `add` a file that's *already in* the index, that means that the new commit still *has* the file, but it has the *previous version* of the file.

Note that, at all times, there are *three* versions of every file you should be concerned with:

- The version in the current commit: `git show HEAD:README.txt`, for instance.  This version of the file is what's *inside the commit*.  It cannot be changed, because no part of any commit can ever be changed.

  You need this to exist *in* the commit so that later, `git clone` or `git checkout` can copy it *out* of the commit, to the index and work-tree.  This version of the file is in a special, Git-only format.  It is compressed, sometimes extremely well.
- The version in the index: `git show :README.txt`, for instance.  This version is what's *in the index / staging-area right now.*  It *can* be changed.  Whatever is in it right now, will go int the next `git commit` you make.

  This version of the file is also in the special, Git-only format.  The chief distinction between the index version and the `HEAD` commit version is that you *can* overwrite the index version.  Whatever is in it at the time you run `git commit`, *that* version will be frozen into that new commit, and hence saved forever (or as long as the new commit continues to exist anyway).
- The version in the work-tree: what you get if you run your editor, or compiler, or whatever, on the file.  This version is really of very little interest to Git itself, even though it's the only one you can use directly.  You can use it because it is *not* in a special, Git-only format.

  This version of the file is mainly useful to Git in terms of `git add`: `git add` compresses this version into a new, special, Git-only format file that Git stuffs into the index, replacing whatever was in that index slot before.  It's useful to *you* because it's a normal file, but Git does not have to care about that, and hence does not care.

When you run `git status`, Git makes two separate comparisons:

- First, Git compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  Whatever is *different* here is "staged for commit".  That's because, if you make a commit right now, Git will use *everything* in the index to make the commit.  So this new commit—which will *become* the current commit—will differ from the current commit, by whatever is different in the index.
- Second, Git compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever is *different* here is "not staged for commit".  That is, you *could* use `git add` to copy the work-tree file back into the index.  If you don't do that, the next commit won't have this version of the file.

Note that you can have all three versions of the file being different!  For instance, after you check out some commit, you can modify the work-tree file, copy the modified file into the index, and then modify the work-tree file some more.  Now you have changes that *are* staged for commit, because `git show HEAD:file` and `git show :file` differ, *and* changes that are *not* staged for commit, because `git show :file` and the contents of the file that Git doesn't use directly, but is in your work-tree, are different too.

#### Control bits in the index

There are two control bits you can set on an entry in the index: *assume unchanged*, and *skip worktree*.  Both of them can be set (or cleared) with `git update-index`, with the `--assume-unchanged`, `--no-assume-unchanged`, `--skip-worktree`, and `--no-skip-worktree` options.

The "assume unchanged" and "skip worktree" bits don't make Git *ignore* a file.  Instead, they affect *how Git goes about comparing the index version of the file to the work-tree version of the file.*  Setting either bit means that `git add .` or `git add --all` *won't* copy the work-tree version into the index, and `git status` *won't* compare the index version to the work-tree version.

It *does not* change the way that the `HEAD`-vs-index comparisons work.  It *does not* change the way `git commit` builds a new commit from whatever is in the index.  It only affects whether Git bothers to compare the index and work-tree versions, and whether Git automatically copies from the work-tree to the index for en-masse `git add` operations.

The two control bits have different intents: *assume unchanged* is meant for use on machines where `git status` is very slow, to speed it up, while *skip worktree* is meant more for what you are doing.  So you should be using `--skip-worktree`.  However, both should have the same effect in general.

Both bits will skip comparisons of the index contents to the work-tree contents.  Git still needs to copy the file from the work-tree into the index to change it, so that if you *don't* copy the file into the index, it won't change.  Each new commit will have the same old version of that file.

Note that if you `git checkout` some *other* commit, or merge commits that you obtained from some other Git, or otherwise change which commit is the *current commit*, Git must *replace* the index version of this file with a new version.  When Git does that, Git will want to *overwrite* the *work-tree* version of the file.  If Git needs to overwrite the work-tree version of the file, Git will—*regardless of any control bits*—first check whether this would overwrite something you never committed.

If *changing* the current commit requires *changing the index version of the file*, and you have something uncommitted in your work-tree, *none of these control bits stop Git from complaining.*  That's normal, and useful to you, because it means that you will have to save *your* (work-tree) version of the file somewhere, and then allow Git to replace your work-tree version with the new version from whichever commit you intend to use as the new current commit.  Once that's happened, it's up to *you* to reconcile your saved work-tree version with the one Git extracted from the now-current commit, and maybe set one of those control bits again.